# Configuration file for the start menu in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 10 the start menu can be personalized for each user. This means for each user there must be a file which specifies what is displayed in the start menu. Where is this file located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Where is the user start menu configuration file located?

> The default Start Menu template is located here:
>
> ```
>  %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\DefaultLayouts.xml
> ```
>
> Which expands to:

```
 C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\DefaultLayouts.xml
```

> This file should not be modified.
>
> To modify the start menu we use the file called
>   `LayoutModification.xml` that should reside in the same directory:

```
 %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\LayoutModification.xml
```

> Which expands to:

```
 C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\LayoutModification.xml
```

> This file can be used in many ways for OEMs to add icons to the Start
>   Menu or for us to override the default Start Menu.
>
> More information on how to use these files can be found on MSDN at
>   [Start layout for Windows 10 desktop
>   editions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt171092(v=vs.85).aspx)
>
> **Exporting a customized Start Menu layout**
>
> To export the Start Menu we start by using a computer and a user and
>   adjust the Start Menu on that computer so it looks the way we want it.
>
> Then we use PowerShell to export a customized start menu using the
>   following command:

```
 Export-Startlayout –path C:\Windows\Temp\Startmenu.xml
```

> **Import a Start Menu layout using PowerShell**
>
> Now that we have an exported Start Menu we can import it using
>   PowerShell. All users that log on to the machine the first time will
>   get this Start Menu layout that you import.

```
 Import-StartLayout –LayoutPath C:\Windows\Temp\Startmenu.xml -MountPath $env:SystemDrive\
```

> After the command is successfully completed the
>   `Layoutmodification.xml` file is created here:

```
 C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Layoutmodification.xml
```

> When we log on to the computer as a "new" user that hasn't logged on
>   the computer before we get the newly imported Start Menu.

Source [Customizing the Windows 10 Start Menu and add IE Shortcut during OSD](http://ccmexec.com/2015/09/customizing-the-windows-10-start-menu-and-add-ie-shortcut-during-osd/)

---

#### Where is the user start menu located?

The user specific start menu is located at:

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```

Which expands to:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) - Environment variables are mainly used within batch files, they can be created, modified and deleted for a session using the SET command.

Comment: Might want to mention that %appdata% is within the user's given profile directory.

Comment: I think he's not referring to the content but how it is arranged.

Comment: There's a "Start Menu" in that folder alright. But which file is the one for configuring what appears in the Start Menu?

Comment: @user3083324 Answer updated

Comment: Why do I have log as a new user? There should be a cmdlet to just update my user profile variables.....

Answer (score 0):

Slight correction to the "XML" path:  "`%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\`"

The "Start Menu" path is correct: "`%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\`"